# github actions that uses a local file that is not commited will fail to build on the server

Tags: android, git, github, github-actions

I am using github actions with an android project. This is my yml file

```
name: Run github actions

on:
push:
  branches: [master, develop]
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - '**' # All branches

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Check out repository code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Upload app to AppSweep with Gradle
        env:
          APPSWEEP_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.APPSWEEP_API_KEY }}
        run: ./gradlew uploadToAppSweepRelease
```

The issue is with the following `local.properties` which contains my API key that I don't want to commit to my repository as its a github public repository.

So when github is buidling it will fail with the following as it can't find that file as its not been committed.

```
* What went wrong:
/home/runner/work/BusbyTasky/BusbyTasky/local.properties (No such file or directory)
```

This is a snippit of where I am using the `local.properties` to get my API key

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdk = 24

    testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    consumerProguardFiles("consumer-rules.pro")

    /* Retrieves API from local.properties */
    val properties = org.jetbrains.kotlin.konan.properties.Properties()
    properties.load(project.rootProject.file("local.properties").inputStream())

    buildConfigField("String", "API_KEY", "\"${properties.getProperty("API_KEY")}\"")
}
```

My question is there a way to build successfully on github without committing the local.properties?

Comment: Forgot to write the question part?

Comment: You may use [Encrypted secrets](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets) to store such sensitive data.